# Access an item in a list in a subsite with Javascript(Solved)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

```
function Testing()
  {

 var context = new SP.ClientContext('/Testing');

  documents = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Site Assets").getItems();
context.load(documents);

  context.executeQueryAsync(CheckedOutItems, TestingonFail);   
}
```

I'm trying to get the items from a document library within a subsite. I have a subsite named Testing and testing have a document library named Site Asset and I want to show these items on my start page of a sitecollection.
(`SharePointServer\Testing\SiteAssets`).

When I'm running this code I get unknown response from `args.get_message()` in `TestingonFail`.

**EDIT:**

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext('/Testing');

var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("TestingDocLib");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
this.documents = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

context.load(documents);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.CheckedOutItems),  Function.createDelegate(this, this.TestingonFail));
```

This one works for me now. I implemented some code from msdn, (The links ali SharePoint gave) and made a new document library named TestingDocLib.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is the list title really "SiteAssets" without a blank?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a typo. I'm using the "Site Assets". It doesn't work either way. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Is REST an option, or does it need to be the client object model?

Comment: for the getItems() function, you need pass a CAML query or AllItems query. See my answer below

Comment: Please add your update as an answer! That way the question can really be put in a solved state

Comment: If people are searching, your question won't show as answered unless you add one and select it as 'accepted'.

Comment: I can't add a answer because of my reputation (10 needed). I'm able to do so in 4 hours. But I accepted Aveenav's answer as 'accepted'. It was exactly/similar to my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

function retrieveListItems() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + 'Testing');

    var web = context.get_web();
    var documents = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Site Assets");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var q = '<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>';
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
    var listItems = documents.getItems(q);
    context.load(listItems, 'Include(Id, Title, FileRef)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListItemsLoadSuccess, onQueryFailed);

    function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
        //iterate though all of the items
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
            var title = item.get_item('Title');
            var id = item.get_id();
            window.console && console.log("Title : " + title + " ID : " + id);
        }
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) nake sure the url is correct

2) as robert noted make sure your list title is correct!

your code is correct, below is taken from msdn:

```
function retrieveWebSite() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/MySiteCollection');
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    this.oList = collList.getByTitle('Site Assets');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539350(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext('/' + allItems[y]); 
listItems = context.get_web().get_lists();
```

code above is only getting the list, what url are you putting into the array?

code should be:

```
function retrieveWebSite() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext('/' + allItems[y]); 
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists(); 

    var oList = list.getByTitle('Site Assets');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

if you can get the list and bove code works than below will show how to get items within the list that you loaded into the context:

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{
    alert('Title: ' + oList.get_title());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: This code works for getting the lists within a subsite. var context = new SP.ClientContext('/' + allItems[y]);
        listItems = context.get_web().get_lists(); But when its the items then I get unknown response.

Comment: just ammended answer